# Linear Transformation Between Infinite Dimensional Vector Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let there be a linear transformation $A$ that maps a vector in $\Bbb{R}^{\aleph _{0}}$ to a vector in $\Bbb{R}^{\aleph _{1}}$. In other words, $A$ maps a vector from a countably infinite vector space to an uncountably infinite vector space.

1. Is $AA^T$ invertible?
2. If $AA^T$ is symmetric then what is an upper bound for its smallest eigenvalue?

Comment: What is $A^T$ in this context?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The transpose of the matrix A

Comment: But $A$ is a linear transformation, not a matrix.

Comment: Take $A$ to be the zero map.